# the shortest path through the entire point in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin, path

I am a beginner in kotlin, I am developing an algo in kotlin.
My goal is to find **the shortest path through all the points**.
For the moment my algo is trying to find the shortest distance from one point to another but I can't improve it.
NOTE: a MapDataPoint is an object with coordinate(latitude and longitude), and a a status represented by string

```
 fun findClosestPoint(latLng: LatLng, points: List<MapDataPoint>): MapDataPoint {
        
        var latestClosestPoint: MapDataPoint? = null
        points.forEach { latestPoint->
            if (latestPoint.status == "present") {
                latestClosestPoint = latestPoint
                points.forEach { point ->
                    if (point.status == "present") {
                        val differenceLatestLng: Double = kotlin.math.abs(latestClosestPoint!!.lng - latLng.longitude)
                        val differenceLatestLat: Double = kotlin.math.abs(latestClosestPoint!!.lat - latLng.latitude)
                        val differenceActuelLng: Double = kotlin.math.abs(point.lng - latLng.longitude)
                        val differenceActuelLat: Double = kotlin.math.abs(point.lat - latLng.latitude)
                        if (differenceActuelLat < differenceLatestLat && differenceActuelLng < differenceLatestLng) {
                            latestClosestPoint = point
                        }
                    }
                }
                return latestClosestPoint!!
            }
        }
        return latestClosestPoint!!
}
```

```
fun displayEpurationPath(mapDatapoint: List<MapDataPoint>) {
        

            val locationComponent = mapboxMap?.locationComponent?.lastKnownLocation
            val latLng = LatLng(locationComponent!!.latitude, locationComponent.longitude)
            var newCoordinate: LatLng? = null
            val points: MutableList<MapDataPoint> = mapDatapoint.toMutableList()
            var sortedList: MutableList<MapDataPoint> = mutableListOf()
            val list: MutableList<MapDataPoint> = emptyList<MapDataPoint>().toMutableList()


            while (points.isNotEmpty() && !manageStatusListPoint(points)) {
                val point: MapDataPoint = if (newCoordinate == null) {
                    findClosestPoint(latLng, points)
                } else {
                     findClosestPoint(newCoordinate, points)
                }
                newCoordinate = LatLng(point.lat, point.lng)
                sortedList.add(point)
                points.remove(point)

}
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWunw.png) is the graphic representation, we can see that it is not the shortest path

Comment: There are well known (and rather old) algorithms for solving this; did you try looking for them?

Comment: Of course I searched before asking my question, that's what I did. Would you have an algorithm to advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is a variant of the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). You just do not want to return to the start point at the end.

I must inform you that there is no 'fast' algorithm known to solve this optimally.
But a lot of methods to find good solutions quite fast.

Common ways to find solutions is backtracking, genetic algorithms, ...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, thank you very much for your help, but I've done a search on the internet for examples, tracking is generally used in the resolution of mazes and I don't see how to adapt it to the GPS coordinates of my points.

Comment: Your points are simply vertices in a fully-connected graph.

Comment: yes that's right all the points are connected to each other, I created a class that contains two points with a distance to them. Then I create a list of this object which corresponds to all the possible connections

Comment: The point is that is EXACTLY what the Travelling Salesman Problem solves.

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you have any idea how I can implement the travelling salesman algo or a site that could help me to do so ? I've done my research and none of them take into account the GPS coordinates

Comment: The only part of this that's specific to GPS co-ordinates is being able to calculate the distance between any two of your points.  Assuming you can do that, the rest is a completely general TSP, and so _any_ TSP algorithm should be usable.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traveling-salesman-problem-tsp-implementation/
 but I'm having a little trouble initializing my graph for the distance calculation I used "TurfMeasurement.distance".